# Mockito RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS throws nullpointer exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am having some problems mocking the ClientResponseWrapper class. I have mocked it and added the "RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS" parameter to be able to mock chained calls. I keep getting the "NullPointerException" and do not know why.
Could you help me please.

Here is the code:

```
package com.service.external_data.application.synchronize_bookings;

import com.service.external_data.domain.BookingUpdateQueueItem;
import com.service.external_data.domain.repository.BookingUpdateQueueRepository;
import com.service.external_data.domain.repository.KeyValueRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Transaction2Test {

    @Mock
    private KeyValueRepository keyValueRepository;

    @Mock
    private BookingUpdateQueueRepository bookingUpdateQueueRepository;;

    @Mock
    private BookingClient bookingClient;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<List<BookingUpdateQueueItem>> bookingUpdateQueueItemCaptor;

    @InjectMocks
    private Transaction transaction;

    @Test
    public void testRunSuccessResponse() {
        Integer startIndex = 456;
        when(keyValueRepository.getFromIndex()).thenReturn(startIndex);

        ClientResponseWrapper<BookingUpdateResponse> clientResponse = mock(ClientResponseWrapper.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

        BookingUpdateDto bookingUpdateDto = mock(BookingUpdateDto.class);
        when(bookingUpdateDto.getBookingNumber()).thenReturn("12345");

        List<BookingUpdateDto> bookingUpdateDtos = List.of(bookingUpdateDto);

        when(clientResponse.getResponseBody().getData()).thenReturn(bookingUpdateDtos);
        when(clientResponse.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);

        List<BookingUpdateDto> bookings = mock(List.class);
        BookingUpdateResponse bookingUpdateResponse = mock(BookingUpdateResponse.class);
        when(clientResponse.getResponseBody()).thenReturn(bookingUpdateResponse);
        when(bookingUpdateResponse.getData()).thenReturn(bookings);

        when(bookingClient.requestBookingUpdates(startIndex)).thenReturn(clientResponse);

        Integer nextIndex = 678;
        when(bookingUpdateResponse.getNextFrom()).thenReturn(nextIndex);

        transaction.run();

        verify(bookingUpdateQueueRepository).saveAll(bookingUpdateQueueItemCaptor.capture());

        Integer listSize = bookingUpdateQueueItemCaptor.getValue().size();

        assertEquals(1, listSize);
        verify(keyValueRepository).setFromIndex(nextIndex);
    }
}
```

The exception is:
java.lang.NullPointerException at line:
"when(clientResponse.getResponseBody().getData()).thenReturn(bookingUpdateDtos);"

Complete stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.service.external_data.application.synchronize_bookings.Transaction2Test.testRunSuccessResponse(Transaction2Test.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

Comment: You have to set the Response body object first. e.g when(clientResponse.getResponseBody()).thenReturn( the Data object);

Comment: But shouldn't the "RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS" functionality take care of all the intermediate calls of the mock?

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace to your question.

Comment: You can check what Mockito has to say about clean code and verification. There is a WARNING associated with it. link : https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS

Comment: Is `ClientResponseWrapper` a class you wrote, and is it `public` and non-`final`? (Or is it an interface?) Is `getResponseBody()` also `public` and non-`final`? Which line is line 60? Finally, why are you mocking `getResponseBody().getData()` and then replacing it with your own `bookingUpdateResponse`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find solve the problem. As mentioned by Jeff Bowman, I was mocking the response of "bookingUpdateResponse.getData()" "twice", and I think because of this the exception was thrown. I was able to write the test without the "RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS" (by mocking intermediate calls):

Result:

```
    @Test
    public void testRunSuccessResponse() {
        Integer startIndex = 456;
        when(keyValueRepository.getFromIndex()).thenReturn(startIndex);

        ClientResponseWrapper<BookingUpdateResponse> clientResponse = mock(ClientResponseWrapper.class);

        BookingUpdateDto bookingUpdateDto = mock(BookingUpdateDto.class);
        when(bookingUpdateDto.getBookingNumber()).thenReturn("12345");

        List<BookingUpdateDto> bookingUpdateDtos = List.of(bookingUpdateDto);

        when(clientResponse.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);

        BookingUpdateResponse bookingUpdateResponse = mock(BookingUpdateResponse.class);
        when(clientResponse.getResponseBody()).thenReturn(bookingUpdateResponse);
        when(bookingUpdateResponse.getData()).thenReturn(bookingUpdateDtos);

        when(bookingClient.requestBookingUpdates(startIndex)).thenReturn(clientResponse);

        Integer nextIndex = 678;
        when(bookingUpdateResponse.getNextFrom()).thenReturn(nextIndex);

        transaction.run();

        verify(bookingUpdateQueueRepository).saveAll(bookingUpdateQueueItemCaptor.capture());

        Integer listSize = bookingUpdateQueueItemCaptor.getValue().size();

        assertEquals(1, listSize);
        verify(keyValueRepository).setFromIndex(nextIndex);
    }
```

Thank you all for your helpful comments!